# Reload other tab from cell ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have two tabs: contacts and favorites. All of them are loaded on app start. In contacts tab I have a list of contacts with a button "addToFavorites" in each cell.

This is the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    contactsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"contactCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    User *us = [usersData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.actualLoggedUser = self.actualLoggedUser;
    cell.contactsUserId = us.userId;
    cell.contactsName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",us.fname,us.lname];
    [cell.contactsImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:us.imageName]];
    return cell;
}
```

When i click the addToFavorites button in the cell, this method is called:

```
- (IBAction)contactsAddToFav:(id)sender{
    [[[ModelUser instance] getUser:self.actualLoggedUser] addFavUser:self.contactsUserId];
}
```

The model is updated correctly but I need two things:
1. I want somehow to call the reload function on the favoritesTableViewController from the contactsTableViewController. For example: when i run the app i see 3 contacts in favorite tab and after adding another one (from contacts tab), I should see 4 contacts.
2. In addition, I want to update the favorites list after clicking on delete button in favoritesTableViewCell in favorites tab.

```
- (void)reloadData {

    NSLog(@"Favorites tab was loaded");

    //get id of my favorite contacts
    myFavListId = [[ModelUser instance] getUser:self.actualLoggedUser].contactsFavoriteList;

    //get data of my favorites contacts
    myFavListContactsData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i < [myFavListId count] ; i++) {
        User* us = [[ModelUser instance] getUser:([myFavListId objectAtIndex:i])];
        [myFavListContactsData addObject:us];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

[contacts tab](http://postimg.org/image/ivx9ky5th/)

[favorites tab](http://postimg.org/image/w9bjpuoa1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier way could be to reload the FavoritesTable in ViewDidAppear of the favoritesTableviewController.

Another way could be to pass the information that Favorites data has changed to favoritesTableViewController.

1) Create a SettingsManagerSingleton with refreshPending Flag and share it to both child view controllers.

2) In ContactsTableViewController if there is fav change, set the flag to true.

3) In viewWillAppear of FavoritesTableViewController, check if refreshPending is set to true and refresh the table. Also set the flag to false after reload.

Comment: How can i realod data in favorites tab after delete from favorite cell (call from cell to same tableviewcontroller)